# sorting in map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement a simple problem in map reduce-transpose of a matrix.
Input:

```
   1 2 3 
   4 5 6 
   7 8 9
```

Desired output-

```
   1 4 7 
   2 5 8 
   7 8 9
```

My map output is

```
(0,1) (1,4), (2,7), (0,2) (1,5), (2,8)
```

and so on.

I was expecting to use the reducer method method as `0-{1,2,7} , 1-{4,5,8}` and directly use write to write the object in serialized form. But the shuffle and sort is not giving the desired output. After the map method i am getting the output as  `0-{1,7,2} , 1-{5,4,8}`.

How SS is working in this case if my key is common. And also what will be solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

The keys will be sorted as they come into the reduce phase, the values in the given value sets will not be sorted.
There is no guarantee for order in the values passed into the reducer, that is not how Hadoop works.

Your problem is (as you say) a 'simple problem' [in many other different frameworks and paradigms]. This problem is *not* an easy (or **appropriate**) problem for map reduce.

---

A solution to your situation is to have more complex keys to make sure the output is in the order you want initially, or to pass the output through a secondary sort map reduce job creating composite keys from the key and individual values.

Comment: @BenWatson You're absolutely right! While I intimated towards it (and now explicitly mentioned it), the original question indicated some confusion about shuffle-sort that I wanted to address before offering any other sort of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Order of value is not guaranteed for reduce input.

You can do the sort using 2nd MapReduce program
or 
You can use comparator. Here is a nice blog addressing the case
https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a value that contains also the column index.

```
public class ColumnValue implements Writable{


    public double column;
    public double value;

    public PartialWritablePhase1(long column, double value){
        this.column = column;
        this.value = value;     
    }


    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.column = in.readLong();
        this.value = in.readDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(column);
        out.writeDouble(value);


    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return column+" "+value;
}


}
```

You then can use it in the reducer as such

```
public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<ColumnValue> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (ColumnVal val : values) {
            //Store values of column in OrderedByColumn an ordered tree set by column
           // or any structure you want
        }


        Iterator<ColumnValue> keySetIterator = OrderedByColumn.iterator();

        while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){

          context.write(new LongWritable(key.get()), keySetIterator.next());
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to force sorting of the values in the Reducer, will be to create a custom composite key and to implement your own group comparator. This will achieve what you want.

```
public class CompositeKey implements WritableComparable<CompositeKey> {
    private int id;
    private int order;

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        id = in.readInt();
        order = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeInt(order);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CompositeKey other) {
        if(this.id != other.id) {
            return this.id - other.id;
        }
        return this.order - other.order;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

The id field corresponds to the key that your Mapper outputs. The order field corresponds to the order you want your values to appear for each key in the Reducer.
Eg your Mapper should now output (key:{id=0,order=0},value:1) for the first element and (key:{id=0,order=1},value:2) for the second element. This way you will have your elements ordered.

Finally, in order to have your key-value pairs groupped by key id only, you will need to write your own group comparator.

```
public class CompKeyGroupComparator extends WritableComparator {
    public CompKeyGroupComparator() {
        super(CompositeKey.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
        CompositeKey lKey = (CompositeKey) a;
        CompositeKey rKey = (CompositeKey) b;
        return lKey.getId() - rKey.getId();
    }
}
```

To set the GroupComparator:

```
job.setGroupingComparatorClass(CompKeyGroupComparator.class);
```

Now your reducer will get the values with the order you gave in your Mappers.
0-{1,2,7} , 1-{4,5,8} etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is probably caused by the use of quicksort on the map side when sorting in buffer. Quicksort is not stable.

(But I found that InsertSort is used when the number is less than 13.
InsertSort is stable, so I'm not sure if QuickSort is responsible for the 9 key-value pairs here.